# How to pass list of items to Web Service

Tags: c#, xml

Good day

I have a list that I serialize and pass to Controller , on button click I have `requestList` which I fill with data
`List<LabOrderLineItemRequest> requestList = new List<LabOrderLineItemRequest>();`

Here is `string responseList` for which I call the method to serialize the data

```
  string responseList = Project.DTO.Helpers.MessageRelay.SendRequests(uriStringList, "POST", "application/json", requestList, _sessionToken);
        List<LabOrderLineItemResponse> objList = ((List<LabOrderLineItemResponse>)(Project.DTO.Serialization.ObjectXmlSerialization.DeserializeFromXML(responseList.ToString(), typeof(List<LabOrderLineItemResponse>))));
        if ((!(objList == null) && (objList.GetType() == typeof(List<LabOrderLineItemResponse>))))
        {

        }
```

This is the method that does the serialization

```
 public static string SendRequest(string uriString, string Method, string ContentType, object postBody, string Base64Key)
    {
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(uriString);
        myWebRequest.Method = Method;
        myWebRequest.ContentType = ContentType;
        myWebRequest.Timeout = 300000;        

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format(xml, Base64Key));
        myWebRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = myWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();



        try
        {
            System.Net.WebResponse response = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
            //Read response
            System.IO.StreamReader objStreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string output = objStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            output = output.Replace("<string>", "").Replace("</string>", "");
            string dcypher = "";
            try
            {
                dcypher = Encryption.AESClass.AESDecrypt(output, Base64Key);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dcypher = output;
            }
            return dcypher;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }

    }
```

Finally the `SendRequest` will call the controller, but the problem is that when the code calls the controller it passes NULL on `request` . `object postBody` does comes with the list that im passing so the only problem is after serializing the data, it then not pass them to a controller. Please let me know if you do not understand so that i can elaborate again. Thank you

```
  [System.Web.Http.Route("api/lineitem")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost()]
    public List<LabOrderLineItemResponse> LabOrderLineItem(List<LabOrderLineItemRequest> request)
    {
        AuthenticateITProcess lab = new AuthenticateITProcess();
        // return lab.CreateLabLineItem(request);
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're expecting an object sent to your controller, whether that be Json or XML. But you're encrypting a string in a non-supported format. So when the controller goes to deserialize the message, it can't due to you not using a format.

If you want to use your own specific encryption algorithm you and object format, you will need to take a string into your controller and then deserialize it yourself.

Comment: Also make sure that you send the appropriate `Content-Type` header

Comment: Any way i can use to send List<> items from UI.Web form to Controller? Please share some code if you have. Thanks

Comment: Is encrypting it a requirement? Is HTTPS not enough?

Answer (score 0):

So what i did was to pass the list of items from Web.UI webform straight to a controller.
He is how i did it . I is passing value to a controller .

```
string uriStringList = (uriRoutePrefix);
        string inputJson = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(requestList);

        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(uriStringList));
        httpRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputJson);

        using (Stream stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
               string lblOutput = (new StreamReader(stream)).ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```